# In Google Sheets, is there a way to override other conditional formatting rules when the goal is to highlight the whole row?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J1dW6f-BF81UxhjwM_6jF79Aio-lZPdS5LYGjGS9s3Q/edit?usp=sharing) to a copy of my data to mess around with. I have given permission to edit so you can see if it works.

What I want my data to look like this:

[image: Thick borders represent where I would like purple (Missing) to highlight. This would be determined by the lack of due date in E:F]

- For a given course title (determined by column B), I want columns B:F to be highlighted in a specific color assigned to that class)
- If due date (determined by E:F) is BLANK, **AND** assignment name (determined by text in column C) for a given row is ***not*** BLANK, then highlight the observation (row) in purple from C:F. This will help me know what I missed when I was hospitalized and there would be no due date because my professors just want me to turn it in.
- If **BOTH** due date and course title are blank, I do not want any highlighting.

My problem is not point 1, but when I tried some formulas, it

I have tried:

```
= $C:$C = AND((NOT(ISBLANK($C:$C))), (ISBLANK(E:F)))
= $C:$C = AND((NOT(ISBLANK(C:C))), (ISBLANK(E:F)))
= $C:F = AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B180)),(ISBLANK(E:F)))
= $C:$C = AND((ISBLANK($B:B)),(ISBLANK(D2:D)))
= $C:$C = AND(ISBLANK(E:F))
= $C:$C = IFS((ISBLANK(E:F)), NOT(ISBLANK($B:$B)))
= $C:$C = AND((ISBLANK(E:F)), NOT(ISBLANK($B:$B)))
```

Thank you in advance. I could look up someone else's template, but I am legitimately interested in getting better at solving problems like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
=AND((ISBLANK($E:$E)), ISBLANK($F:$F), NOT(ISBLANK($C:$C)))
```

If you put this rule higher in the list of conditional formatting rules, it will take precedence over the rules that color the cells according to course title.

Comment: Yes! That ended up working. I was close, but I see that combining E:F did not work where separating E and F did. Thanks!